# Fetch the data last updated data from one2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can I fetch the data **last updated data from one2many field**. I used the following code but it is not work when I create a new record and for existing records it works fine.

**Code**

```
class location(models.Model):
_name = 'weather.location'

name = fields.Char(string="City Name",required=True)
weather_ids = fields.One2many('weather.weather', 
                'location_id', string="Weather Details", domain=([('forecast','=',False)]))
temperature = fields.Float(string='Temperature', compute='weather_details')
def weather_details(self):
    for record in self:
        temperature_list = []
        for line in record.weather_ids:
            temperature_list.append(line.temperature)
        self.temperature = record.temperature_list[-1]
```

When I created the new one it gives the following **error**:

> self.temperature=temperature_list[-1]
>   
> IndexError: list index out of range

Can anybody help how to get the last updated data from one2many fiel

Answer (score 1):

The variable temperature_list is an array, you could access last position with temperature_list[:-1], so if you change the line:

```
self.temperature=temperature_list[-1]
```

by

```
self.temperature=temperature_list[:-1]
```

It must work